# Why are my getName() and getSalary() causing errors? Should they not be pulling from the other class?

Tags: java

The only error I have showing up is that the getName() and getSalary() are not found in there class.  I am trying to get the information that is entered into the testEmployee class to use use Employee and display the results.  I get a Build Successful message but no output.

```
public abstract class Person {

    // Variables
    private String name;
    private String ssn = null;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Pass data to the object Person
    /**
     * 
     * @param ssn
     */
    public void setSsn(String ssn) {
        this.ssn = ssn;
    }

    public String getSsn() {
        return ssn;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public abstract String getName();

}

class Employee extends Person {

    // Variables
    private String jobTitle;
    private double salary;
    private String getName;
    private double cost;

    public Employee(String name) {
        super(name);

        salary = 0;
        jobTitle = null;

    }

    // Pass values to the obljects
    // Setters
    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }

    public void setSalary(double cost) {
        salary = cost;
    }

    // Getters
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return getName();
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return getJobTitle();
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    /**
     * @return the jobTitle
     */
    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    /**
     * @return the getName
     */
    public String getGetName() {
        return getName;
    }

    /**
     * @param getName
     *            the getName to set
     */
    public void setGetName(String getName) {
        this.getName = getName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the cost
     */
    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    /**
     * @param cost
     *            the cost to set
     */
    public void setCost(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }
}

public class testEmployee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee("John Smith");
        String ssn = "333224444";
        String jobTitle = "Web Designer";
        double cost = 60000;
        System.out.println("Employee " + getName() "\n The current compensation is " + getSalary());
    }
}
```

Comment: It would *really* help if you'd sort out the indentation on your code before posting it. It's very hard to read at the moment.

Comment: looks like getName() is going to cause some infinite recursion.  Guess that's why we call this site `StackOverflow`

Comment: It does.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove `getName` and `getGetName()`, and just make `getName()` return `name`.

Comment: OK that gets it to print the name but not the salary and I still have the ')' expected error.

Comment: Reimeus found it earlier; you're missing a plus sign after `getName()` on the `System.out.println` line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have `emp1.getName()` and `emp1.getSalary()` instead of `getName()` and `getSalary()` in your `println` function in `main`

Comment: When I do that I get an ')' expected error and when I run I get a stackoverflow error.

Comment: Read @Gus comment. In your `getName()` function you are stating `return getName()` which is just going to call the function again, resulting in infinite recursion. Try changing the code in your `getName()` function in the `Employee` class.

Answer (score 4):

Use the instance of `Employee` `emp1` created in the `main` method when invoking the `getName` and `getSalary` methods:

```
System.out.println
  ("Employee " + emp1.getName() + "\n The current compensation is " + emp1.getSalary());
```

Notice the additional `+` operator after `getName()`

Also you've got an `StackOverflowError` scenario here where `getName` is recusively calling itself *ad infinitum*

```
@Override
public String getName() {
   return getName();
}
```

Since `name` is a class member variable of `Person` implement this method there

```
public String getName() {
   return name;
}
```

The same applies to `getTitle` in `Employee`. Replace

```
public String getTitle() {
   return getJobTitle();
}
```

with

```
public String getTitle() {
   return jobTitle;
}
```